# sql sum from two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got two separate tables in sqlite called invoices and purchases and I am using the query below to retrieve the sum of all the invoices and purchases that related to project 7. The thing is the invoices have three records and the value returned in sql is correct, however the purchase equivalent is wrong as there is only one record, but the returned value is multiplied by three.

```
SELECT sum(invoice.invoice_net) As Sales, sum(purchase.total_order) As Purchases
FROM invoice
LEFT JOIN purchase
ON purchase.projectID=invoice.projectID
WHERE invoice.projectID=7
```

How can I join these two statements so I get the data returned correctly. I know individually they work fine. I've tried Union, but that puts the data into one column.

```
SELECT sum(invoice.invoice_net) As Sales
FROM invoice
WHERE projectID=7

SELECT sum(purchase.order_total) As Purchases
FROM purchase
WHERE projectID=7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `sum` the results using subqueries and then perform the `outer join`:

```
SELECT invoice.Sales, purchase.Purchases
FROM (
    SELECT sum(invoice.invoice_net) As Sales, projectID
    FROM invoice
    GROUP BY projectID
) invoice LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sum(total_order) As Purchases, projectID
    FROM purchase 
    GROUP BY projectID
) purchase ON purchase.projectID=invoice.projectID
WHERE invoice.projectID=7
```

---

Another option would be to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT sum(i.invoice_net) As Sales,
    (SELECT sum(p.total_order) 
    FROM purchase p
    WHERE p.projectID = i.projectID) As Purchases
FROM invoice i
WHERE i.projectID=7
```